# QnA maker API is taking around 15-30 seconds to respond few times randomly

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

This is the code sample i am trying to connect to QnA maker in node js

```
var extServerOptionsPost={
  host:'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com',
  path:'/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/' + your_kb + '/generateAnswer',
  port:443,
  method:'POST',
  headers:{
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':your_key,
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
  }
};
```

Most of the times the response from QnA maker is with in 1-2 seconds, but sometimes the response time is going up to 30 seconds. And the delay is random/intermittent.

QnA maker has only around 150 questions and 2 knowledgebases.

Any idea on why is this happening?

Comment: The best place to start your troubleshooting will be from the App Service associated with your QnA Maker KB in Azure Portal. Review the app service plan and then look into the logs.

Comment: Is your bot making any other API calls that might be interfering with the QnA response being received? Also, does this occur randomly within a conversation, at the same point in the conversation but not every time, at the beginning of a conversation but not every time, or some other scenario?

Comment: @StevenKanberg there are no other API calls are making by the bot.This occurs randomly in between a conversation or sometimes at the beginning of a conversation. This delay is mostly limited to only 1 or 2 questions continuously and after that there is no delay in the response.

Comment: Thanks @RajeshSitaraman . I will take a look into it.